# Can't enable user interaction with NSNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c

I got a button, when I click this it set userInteraction: `self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` this works, and if I click the button I can't click on it anymore. Then I got a `receiveNotification` that I call in another class.

```
- (void) receiveNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{    
   if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"EnableUI"]){
       self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
       NSLog(@"Successfully received the %@ notification!",[notification name]);
   }
}
```

The program output tells me that the notification is received, since it prints out `Successfully received the EnableUI notification!` However, I still cannot click on the UI button...

Comment: first thing to test in this case, is self.view != nil ? (I assume so, but I always begin by testing trivial things) I would also make sure to perform the work on the main thread. You could also try a [self.view becomeFirstResponder]; after setting userInteractionEnabled to yes

Comment: self.view is nil, I tried the becomeFirstResponder, but this doesn't work

Comment: if self.view is nil, no wonder becomeFirstResponder does not work, try to know why the view isn't set, maybe put a NSLog("viewDidLoad") in the viewDidLoad method of your controller and look which is first (successfully received the %@ notification or viewDidLoad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to set userInteraction on the view, which you don't seem to need in this case, why not set the interaction on the button itself?

**.H**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonA;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonB;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonC;
```

**.M**

```
@synthesize buttonA, buttonB, buttonC;

- (void) receiveNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{  
   NSArray *buttonArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:buttonA,buttonB,buttonC,nil];  
   if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"EnableUI"]){
      for(UIButton* button in buttonArray) {
         UIButton *tempElement = [buttonArray objectAtIndex:i];
         tempElement.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
      }
      NSLog(@"Successfully received the %@ notification!",[notification name]);
   }
}
```

Comment: I got some other buttons on the view that I also want to disable

Comment: @nonuma The array solution is better and quicker. Put all the buttons in an array, and use a for-loop to set i in array.length as enabled or disabled

Comment: @nonuma Have you even connected the view up to anything? What is it's value?

Comment: I'm using storyboard, the view is actually a navigation controller

Comment: Can you give me an example of putting the button that are on my storyboard in an array?

Comment: @nonuma self.navigationController.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

Comment: Actually it inherit from UIViewController

Comment: I've just tried the above code, but still, the notification is successfully received but I cannot click on the buttons...

Comment: Yes, I've connected the storyboard buttons with the property code

Comment: I've tried: if(self.view != nil) NSLog(@"view is not nil"); and the view is NOT nil...

Comment: There must be another problem with your code, because this will work. Try using this as the for loop instead - for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) view.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

Comment: I justt ried it, I've put a NSlog in the for loop and it prints it out twice, but it still doesn't work, I still cannot click on the buttons

Comment: @nonuma There is another problem with your code/subviews etc. if this isn't working..

Answer (score 0):

UIOperations have to be done in main thread.

I suspect you are not on main thread. Please check it in notification method

```
NSLog(@"%i", [NSThread isMainThread]);
```

If not
Please check if you call postNotification method on main thread.

If it is the issue follow the link

[When responding to NSNotifications, what is the best practice for updating UIViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292004/when-responding-to-nsnotifications-what-is-the-best-practice-for-updating-uivie)

Answer (score 0):

Use UIButton.tag to mark buttons which should be disabled.

```
#define BUTTON_TAG_UNAUTH 123

- (void)disableButtonWithReason:(NSUInteger)reason
{
    NSArray *views = [self.view subviews];
    for (UIView *button in views) {
        //first checking tag cause more efficiently
        if (button.tag == reason && [button isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            ((UIButton*)button).enabled = false;
        }
    }
}

- (void)disableButtonsDueToUnauthorized
{
    [self disableButtonWithReason:BUTTON_TAG_UNAUTH];
}
```